# Power transformer secondary 250-0-250, 3.15-0-3.15 3.15-0-3.15. How do I connect to circuit board to have 6.3vac?

Tags: power

Power transformer secondary 250v-0-250v,  3.15-0-3.15, 3.15-0-3.13.  To get 6.3v how do I connect the taps?

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! Should be from 3.15 to the other 3.15 within the same group, but your primary is a bit strange with 250-0-250. Can you take a photo? Do you have access to a multimeter?

Comment: TY.  Actually 250v is on secondary side and transformer has one primary of 117v.Does 0v wire get grounded?

Comment: Oh! That makes sense. See Transistor’s answer below.

Answer (score 1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWCvxS.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Two options: independent 6.3 V supplies or paralleled supplies for greater current. The 250 - 0 - 250 secondary is not shown.*

Normally transformers like this have split primaries of 120 V each as I've indicated here. They're connected in parallel for 110 V systems and in series for 230 V systems.